# Web Method can't find page aspx

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have this HTML  Markup

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCustomers" runat="server">
```

The ASP.Net DropDownList items (options) will be populated by fetching data from database in JSON format by calling WebMethod using jQuery AJAX in ASP.Net.

Client Side using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Regione.aspx/GetRegioni",
   data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
        var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=ddlCustomers]");
        ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
        $.each(r.d, function () {
            ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
        });
    }
});
```

})

VB:NET

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function GetRegioni() As List(Of ListItem)
        Dim query As String = "SELECT IDRegione, NomeRegione FROM TB_REGIONI"
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                Dim regioni As New List(Of ListItem)()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While sdr.Read()
                        regioni.Add(New ListItem() With {
                          .Value = sdr("IDRegione").ToString(),
                          .Text = sdr("NomeRegione").ToString()
                        })
                    End While
                End Using
                con.Close()
                Return regioni
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

When I run the code I have this error:"jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:65122/GetRegioni/Regione.aspx 404 (Not Found)"

Where could be the mistake? I can not find it.

Comment: please share screenshot of the error you getting or describe error.

Comment: you are posting ajax without any data first try GET instead of post 2nd i dont know about vb but in c# the webmethod function needs to be static

Comment: the url seems wrong, look at the error.

Comment: The "shared" keyword in VB.NET is the equivalent of the "static" keyword in C #. The error is:"jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:65122/Regione.aspx/GetRegioni 404 (Not Found)"